# DeserializeObject is not working with this response. What can I do

Tags: api, xamarin.forms, json-deserialization

This is the postman response data.

{"Table":[{"newcust":0}],"Table1":[{"ymon":"201706","ttlsalamtmon":0.000000,"collamtmon":0.000000,"tarcollamt":0.000000,"targtsaleamt":0.000000}],"Table2":[{"schdate":"2017-06-06T00:00:00","ttlsalamtday":0.000000,"collamtday":0.000000,"percn":0.0000000000000000}],"Table3":[{"ymon":"31-May","yearmon":"2017-05-31T00:00:00","ttlsalamt":0.000000,"collamt":0.000000},{"ymon":"01-Jun","yearmon":"2017-06-01T00:00:00","ttlsalamt":0.000000,"collamt":0.000000},{"ymon":"02-Jun","yearmon":"2017-06-02T00:00:00","ttlsalamt":0.000000,"collamt":0.000000},{"ymon":"03-Jun","yearmon":"2017-06-03T00:00:00","ttlsalamt":0.000000,"collamt":0.000000},{"ymon":"04-Jun","yearmon":"2017-06-04T00:00:00","ttlsalamt":0.000000,"collamt":0.000000},{"ymon":"05-Jun","yearmon":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","ttlsalamt":0.000000,"collamt":0.000000},{"ymon":"06-Jun","yearmon":"2017-06-06T00:00:00","ttlsalamt":0.000000,"collamt":0.000000}],"Table4":[],"Table5":[{"ymon":"201701","yearmon":"Jan ' 2017","ttlsalamt":0.000000,"collamt":0.000000,"targtsaleamt":0.000000,"tarcollamt":0.000000},{"ymon":"201702","yearmon":"Feb ' 2017","ttlsalamt":0.000000,"collamt":0.000000,"targtsaleamt":0.000000,"tarcollamt":0.000000},{"ymon":"201703","yearmon":"Mar ' 2017","ttlsalamt":0.000000,"collamt":0.000000,"targtsaleamt":0.000000,"tarcollamt":0.000000},{"ymon":"201704","yearmon":"Apr ' 2017","ttlsalamt":0.000000,"collamt":0.000000,"targtsaleamt":0.000000,"tarcollamt":0.000000},{"ymon":"201705","yearmon":"May ' 2017","ttlsalamt":0.000000,"collamt":0.000000,"targtsaleamt":0.000000,"tarcollamt":0.000000},{"ymon":"201706","yearmon":"Jun ' 2017","ttlsalamt":0.000000,"collamt":0.000000,"targtsaleamt":0.000000,"tarcollamt":0.000000},{"ymon":"201707","yearmon":"Jul ' 2017","ttlsalamt":0.000000,"collamt":0.000000,"targtsaleamt":0.000000,"tarcollamt":0.000000},{"ymon":"201708","yearmon":"Aug ' 2017","ttlsalamt":0.000000,"collamt":0.000000,"targtsaleamt":0.000000,"tarcollamt":0.000000},{"ymon":"201709","yearmon":"Sep ' 2017","ttlsalamt":0.000000,"collamt":0.000000,"targtsaleamt":0.000000,"tarcollamt":0.000000},{"ymon":"201710","yearmon":"Oct ' 2017","ttlsalamt":0.000000,"collamt":0.000000,"targtsaleamt":0.000000,"tarcollamt":0.000000},{"ymon":"201711","yearmon":"Nov ' 2017","ttlsalamt":0.000000,"collamt":0.000000,"targtsaleamt":0.000000,"tarcollamt":0.000000},{"ymon":"201712","yearmon":"Dec ' 2017","ttlsalamt":0.000000,"collamt":0.000000,"targtsaleamt":0.000000,"tarcollamt":0.000000}],"Table6":[{"sirdesc":"None","suamt":0.000000},{"sirdesc":"None","suamt":0.000000},{"sirdesc":"None","suamt":0.000000},{"sirdesc":"None","suamt":0.000000},{"sirdesc":"None","suamt":0.000000}],"Table7":[{"sirdesc":"None","suamt":0.000000},{"sirdesc":"None","suamt":0.000000},{"sirdesc":"None","suamt":0.000000},{"sirdesc":"None","suamt":0.000000},{"sirdesc":"None","suamt":0.000000}],"Table8":[{"sirdesc":"None","suamt":0.000000},{"sirdesc":"None","suamt":0.000000},{"sirdesc":"None","suamt":0.000000},{"sirdesc":"None","suamt":0.000000},{"sirdesc":"None","suamt":0.000000}],"Table9":[{"sirdesc":"None","suamt":0.000000},{"sirdesc":"None","suamt":0.000000},{"sirdesc":"None","suamt":0.000000},{"sirdesc":"None","suamt":0.000000},{"sirdesc":"None","suamt":0.000000}]}

This is my code for calling API.

internal class SalesDashService
{
Constants constant = new Constants();

```
    DataSet SalesDashBoardData = new DataSet();

    public async Task<DataSet> GetSalesDashInfo(string comcode)
    {
        try
        {
            string url = constant.Url + "/api/Mis/ShowSalesDashBoard?comcod=3101&date1=06-Jun-2017&typedata=3";

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
                var response = await client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    SalesDashBoardData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(data);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return SalesDashBoardData;
    }

}
```

My boss said he sent dataset from Backend API

But I couldn't get any data or dataset from this API response. What can I do??

Comment: is the problem deserializing the response, or getting the response back in the first place?  What is the http response code?  Do you get a timeout?  Or an exception?  Please clearly explain what the exact problem is.

Comment: You must also post the declaration of all `DataSet` classes & subclasses.